# Why does updating the state of my React component mess up the iteration?

Tags: reactjs, iteration

**What I'm Trying to Do**

I'm working on a component that switches the current player in a multiplayer game. The data received is an array of strings like `['Player 1', 'Player 2, 'Player 3']`. I'm trying to use `i` as an iterator to loop through, so that `currentPlayer` is re-rendered each time.

**Problem**

If I remove `setCurrentPlayer(data[i]);` from `changePlayer`, then i iterates properly:

0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 0, 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 0

Otherwise, it counts like:

0 => 1, 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 0 => 1, 0 => 1, 1 => 2

So the first element becomes unreachable.

Why is the set function affecting the iterator? How do I stop this?

**I Have Tried**

`i++` instead of `i == data.length - 1 ? i = 0 : i++;` and

`setCurrentPlayer(data[i % data.length]);` instead of `setCurrentPlayer(data[i]);`

which has the same issue. I have also tried just iterating `i` and calculating the current player inline, but then the component doesn't automatically re-render, and it doesn't seem very React-y.

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Game = ({ data }) => {
  let i = 0;

  const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(data[0]);
  

  const changePlayer = () => {
    i == data.length - 1 ? i = 0 : i++;
    setCurrentPlayer(data[i]);
  }

  const formStyle = {
    position: "relative"
  }

  return(
    <div style={formStyle} data-testid="game">
      <h1 data-testid='currentPlayer' value={currentPlayer}>{currentPlayer}</h1>
      <button data-testid="endTurn" onClick={changePlayer}>End Turn</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: because `i` is defined in the function body and upon rerender maybe it's initialized to 0 again.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi the purpose is to loop back to the beginning of the array once it reaches the end

Comment: My bad, I read the line incorrectly.

Comment: How fast are you clicking the "End Turn" button? As you know, setting into the state is asynchronous, so maybe `changePlayer` is executed multiple times before the state is updated, so it messes up the results.

Comment: @RameshReddy ah, I hadn't considered that, I'll move i to the parent

Comment: It behaves the same even if I leave several seconds between clicks, so I believe that it's accurate in that way

Comment: @Jules  You can update the state in a functional way when the new state depends on the old state. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the player based on the index then it's better to have an `index` state because if you declare it in the function body then you cannot predict when it gets executed.
You can just keep track of the index instead of the player in that index.

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Game = ({ data }) => {

    const [playerIndex, setPlayerIndex] = useState(0);

    const changePlayer = () => {
        setPlayerState(previousIndex => {
            return previousIndex === (data.length - 1) ? 0 : previousIndex + 1;
        })
    }

    const formStyle = {
        position: "relative"
    }

    return (
        <div style={formStyle} data-testid="game">
            <h1 data-testid='currentPlayer'>{data[playerIndex]}</h1>
            <button data-testid="endTurn" onClick={changePlayer}>End Turn</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Game;
```